# Shared Cygwin Install

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, cygwin, symlink

I'm attempting to set up OpenSSH on a bunch of Windows Server 2003 machines in an automated fashion. My goal is to be able to do so using a single version of Cygwin installed on a network drive instead of manually installing it on each machine.

I can install cygwin just fine, but start running into problems when I try to run ssh-host-config.

```
$ ssh-host-config
bash: /usr/bin/ssh-host-config: Permission denied
```

Ok, not a big deal. I chmod 555 everythingin /usr/bin.

```
$ ssh-host-config
/usr/share/csih/cygwin-service-installation-helper.sh: line 689: /usr/bin/awk: cannot execute binary file
```

This is where I get stuck. Running

```
petters@BTSOTTSTBAL507 /usr/bin
$ awk
bash: /usr/bin/awk: cannot execute binary file
```

Here are the contents of awk:

```
!<symlink>gawk.exe
```

Just as a note, I can run gawk.exe just fine and have tried installing Cygwin with the CYGWIN=winsymlinks environment variable set.

I have also noticed the following -

```
petters@BTSOTTSTBAL507 /usr/bin
$ ls -l
total 366592    
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ???????? ????????   54798 Feb  4 19:02 [.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ???????? ????????   23566 May 18  2010 addftinfo.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ???????? ????????  165806 May 18  2010 afmtodit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ???????? ????????    1786 May 17  2010 apropos
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ???????? ????????   47118 Feb  4 19:01 arch.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ???????? ????????    8206 Apr 29 00:43 ascii.exe
```

In other words, the ownership data is messed up.

My impression is that cygwin 1.7.x was portable but maybe not? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues you're facing.

First up is the difference between Cygwin's posix-y view of permissions and ownership vs Windows.
You'll want to read [Using Windows security in Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html). The `????????` is displayed because the files are owned by a user that is not defined on the local machine. If you're in a domain, you can probably run `mkpasswd` and `mkgroup` and using the output to create appropriate `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/groups`. However, they will only include the machine-specific accounts of the host where they were created.

Which segues nicely to the second issue:

Cygwin saves most of its configuration settings in or under `/etc`. So sharing `/etc` across multiple hosts is very difficult. Likewise, most Cygwin processes will assume `/tmp` and `/var` are also machine specific.

You *might* be able to get this to work by creating local directories on each machine, such as: `c:\cygwin\etc`, `c:\cygwin\tmp`, and `c:\cygwin\var`. You will need to populate etc and var with the expected files and directories. Then you'll need to create a /etc/fstab that brings all of these together into a complete filesystem. You'll want to read [Mapping path names](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames) for more on that.

Also keep in mind that any time your network drive is unavailable, any running Cygwin processes may hang, crash, or just behave oddly.

Comment: Thank you - I have some homework to do before I'll be able to get this to work but your answer points me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a bad solution. Ideally, you would script some sort of installer for Cygwin and deploy that. Having said that, I don't believe that the setup.exe for Cygwin can be scripted, or read an answer file, etc. You could wrap it in an MSI using a packager, I suppose.

Comment: Or : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745275/can-i-script-a-cygwin-install-to-include-certain-packages